# Fill shade between x-axis,y-axis and function

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to fill area between x-axis,y-axis and function with gray. So I search and try many things, but I couldn't understand how It Works.. anyone could help me to do this???

[image: function and graph]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\begin{axis}[
axis x line=center ,
axis y line=center ,
xlabel = {$x$} ,
ylabel = {$y$} ,
xtick={-0.3},
ytick={1},
xlabel style={below right} ,
ylabel style={above left} ,
xmin=-1 ,
xmax=4 ,
ymin=-0.5 ,
ymax=1.5,]
\addplot [ mark=none, domain=-
1:4,samples=201,name=plot]
{ 1/(x^2+x+1) *1/(x^2+1)^(1/2) };
\node at (axis cs:2,0.8) {\small
$f(x)=\frac{1}{(x^2+x+1)\sqrt{x^2+1}$};
\node at (axis cs:0.4,0.25) {\small$A$};
```

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to TeX-SE! This is a standard task for the `fillbetween` library. Please note that we use to exchange complete codes, which start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. In this case this is important because if you use a very old version of pgfplots you need `axis cs:`, otherwise you don't. (Also there was a missing `$f(x)=\frac{1}{(x^2+x+1)\sqrt{x^2+1}$`.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis x line=center ,
axis y line=center ,
xlabel = {$x$} ,
ylabel = {$y$} ,
xtick={-0.3},
ytick={1},
xlabel style={below right} ,
ylabel style={above left} ,
xmin=-1 ,
xmax=4 ,
ymin=-0.5 ,
ymax=1.5,]
 \addplot [ mark=none, domain=-1:4,samples=201,name path=plot]
  {1/(x^2+x+1) *1/(x^2+1)^(1/2) };
 \path[name path=xaxis] (-1,0) -- (4,0);
  \addplot [gray!30] fill between [
        of=plot and xaxis,soft clip={domain=0:4}];
 \node at (2,0.8) {\small$f(x)=\frac{1}{(x^2+x+1)\sqrt{x^2+1}}$};
 \node at (0.4,0.25) {\small$A$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with `axis on top` added to the axis options.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping!! I found what I did wrong ^^b